# PDF (dynamic XFA) with field programatically changed using iTextSharp throws SOM error when opened

Tags: c#, itext

Using the iText method pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("target", "value") will set the "target" field to the desired "value". But the resulting PDF, when opened in Reader, throws a SOM expression error.

Code that uses AcroFields.Xfa.FindDatasetsNode("target"), creates and appends a text node (e.g., node.OwnerDocument.CreateTextNode("new text")), followed by appending to the found node (e.g., foundNode.AppendChild(text), also fails.

The only thing I've been able to make work is to save the entire PDF DOM (e.g., doc = pdfReader.AcroFields.Xfa.DomDocument; doc.Save(writer)), then load this DOM into another variable, modify it, and save it back to pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.DomDocument.

But, I end up with a PDF that has "extended features" disabled - despite the fact that I am using "append mode" when opening the stamper (e.g., pdfStamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfStampMS, '\0', **true**).

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

string srcPDF = "c:\\Temp\\PDF\\A3.pdf";
string destPDF = "c:\\Temp\\PDF\\A3-out10.pdf";

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(srcPDF);    
MemoryStream pdfStampMS = new MemoryStream();
PdfStamper pdfStamp = null;
pdfStamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfStampMS, '\0', true);

AcroFields form = pdfStamp.AcroFields;
string s = form.GetField("us - request[0].ContentArea1[0].sfApplicantInformation[0].sfApplicantName[0].firstName[0]");
//Checking, and this does get the value
form.SetField("us - request[0].ContentArea1[0].sfApplicantInformation[0].sfApplicantName[0].firstName[0]", "XYZtest");
s = form.GetField("us - request[0].ContentArea1[0].sfApplicantInformation[0].sfApplicantName[0].firstName[0]");
//Checking again, and this does set the value
pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.Changed = true;
pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.DatasetsNode, true);
pdfStamp.Close();
byte[] content = pdfStampMS.ToArray();
using (var fs = File.Create(destPDF))
{
fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
}
pdfReader.Close();
```

The requested field gets set to the desired value, but when opened the resultant PDF throws this exception: "The SOM expression 'sfAssigneeEmail' for the datRef specified on field 'sfAssigneeEmail', resolved to an incompatible node type of 'dataValue'."

The "extended features" are also diabled.

There are numerous questions like this, and most answers concerning the "extended features" issue simply state "use append mode" - which I believe I am doing. More troubling is this malformed PDF that gets created - I've not seen anyone with a problem that is on point.

Any help or suggestions much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I figured out the problem, and like it always is, it was simple ignorance on my part. I had never really understood what the code:

```
pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.DatasetsNode, true);
```

was for. I assumed it was some sort of magical incantation to get pdfStamper to do it's job. It is not. In fact, it is a very useful beast that allows you to automatically change fields based upon an XML document that you provide.

Once I realized that, the fix was obvious: delete this offending line of code
(e.g., the pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.DatasetsNode, true)) line. Do that, and everything is great.

The revised code would look like this:

```
using System;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

string srcPDF = "c:\\Temp\\PDF\\Input.pdf";
string destPDF = "c:\\Temp\\PDF\\Output.pdf";

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(srcPDF);    
MemoryStream pdfStampMS = new MemoryStream();
PdfStamper pdfStamp = null;
pdfStamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfStampMS, '\0', true);

AcroFields form = pdfStamp.AcroFields;
string s = form.GetField("us - request[0].ContentArea1[0].sfApplicantInformation[0].sfApplicantName[0].firstName[0]");
//Checking, and this does get the value
form.SetField("us - request[0].ContentArea1[0].sfApplicantInformation[0].sfApplicantName[0].firstName[0]", "XYZtest");
s = form.GetField("us - request[0].ContentArea1[0].sfApplicantInformation[0].sfApplicantName[0].firstName[0]");
//Checking again, and this does set the value
pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.Changed = true;
pdfStamp.Close();
byte[] content = pdfStampMS.ToArray();
using (var fs = File.Create(destPDF))
{
fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
}
pdfReader.Close();
```

Comment: Can you share the form to allow easy reproduction of the issue?

Comment: I can! It's a govenrment form here: [link](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/aia0014.pdf).  But, you needn't bother - I figured it out. I complete;y misunderstood the purpose of pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(). I thought it was a "magic wand" to wave at pdfFiller, telling it you're done. It is not.  Long story short, simply remove the pdfStamp.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm() line and it works! But thank you for asking!

Comment: Please post the solution as explicit answer instead of as edit of the question.

Comment: Noted and done.